# Compute the flow $\Phi_t$ of $\mathbb{X}(x,y)=(y,x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be the vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by  $$ \mathbb{X}(x,y) = (y,x). $$ Compute the flow $\Phi_t$ of
$\mathbb{X}$

I was reading through an answer on math.stackexchange entitled "Finding the flow of a pushforward of vector field" and the first part of his problem was this question.

The solution he gave was $\Phi_t(x,y)=(\frac{x+y}{2}e^t+\frac{y-x}{2}e^{-t},\frac{x+y}{2}e^t +\frac{x-y}{2}e^{-t})$

My understanding is that to calculate the flow, you consider: $\Phi_t(x,y)=(\dot{x},\dot{y})=(y,x)$ and try to solve.

Why cant the flow be $\Phi(x,y)=((y-x)e^{-t},(x-y)e^{-t})$?

It is probably a problem with definitions, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not a problem with definition.

Hint. The flow of the linear vector field $Az$ is given by its matrix exponent $e^{tA}z$. In your case
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $z=(x,y)^\top$. Hence you need to calculate
$$
e^{tA}
$$
and see the result.

Addition.

There are different methods to calculate $e^{tA}$, but here I can use simply the defintion
$$
e^{tA}=I+tA+\frac{t^2}{2!}A^2+\ldots
$$
Simply by noting that $A^2=I$ I find
$$
e^{tA}=\begin{bmatrix}
1+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^4}{4!}+\ldots& t+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\ldots\\
t+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\ldots&1+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^4}{4!}+\ldots
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\cosh t&\sinh t\\
\sinh t&\cosh t
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where, as usual,
$$
\cosh t=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2},\quad \sinh t=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}.
$$
Now you can see you flow by multiplying $e^{tA}$ by the vector of initial conditions.

Comment: yes I remember reading that, thanks for the help, will give it another go

Comment: Another hint to see where you are a little confused: not every solution to the system of ODE will give you the flow. Only those, where you can simply replace two arbitrary constants with two initial conditions.

Comment: thanks, can you reference a good source on linear vector fields that would explain all of this, cant seem to find any.

Comment: @Dansmith I am not sure that I can give you an ultimate reference. The flows of linear constant coefficients vector fields are linear transformation groups defined simply by $e^{tA}$. There is not much to learn here. Try Arnold's ODE, if you can get through his deceivably easy-to-understand writings, you will learn the general theory of flows, transformation groups, and vector fieleds.

Comment: I have run into a wall and cannot get close to the solution, using $z(t)=e^{At}z_0$, I get $z(t)=e^t(y_0,x_0)^\top$, what is the best way to proceed? Dont see how I can reach the solution.

Comment: Did you hear about the matrix exponent?

Comment: Yes I understand how that works, is the solution given in my question what I am trying to derive, I can't even get close

Comment: See the addition. If you cannot get through it, you should start with the book I advised you.

Comment: Just figured it out as you posted solution, thank you so much for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see this result without needing to use the exponential map is the following:

For $Y = x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + y\frac{\partial}{ \partial x}$ we obtain the differential equations $x'(t) = y$ and $y'(t) = x$. We note that differentiating either of the equations gives us that $y''(t)=y(t)$ and similarly for $x(t)$. We know that the general solution to each of these equations is $y(t)= d_1e^t +d_2e^{-t}$ and $x(t) = c_1e^t +c_2e^{-t}$. Now our global flow must satisfy $x(0)=y$ and $y(0)=x$, and thus we impose the conditions that $c_1 +c_2 =y$ and $d_1+d_2 =x$. Now given that $x'(t) = y(t)$ we have the following relationship between coefficients: $c_1=d_1$ and $c_2 =-d_2$. Plugging these in to the system of equations above and solving for $c_1$ and $c_2$ we obtain that $c_1 = \frac{x+y}{2}$, and $c_2 = \frac{y-x}{2}$. Thus our flow becomes $\theta_t(x, y) = (\frac{x+y}{2}e^t + \frac{y-x}{2}e^{-t}, \frac{x+y}{2}e^t-\frac{y-x}{2}e^{-t})$.