# Flow of a vector field $f(x,y)=(x,-y+x^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, vector-fields

The two dimensional system is given below

$\dot{x}=x$,

$\dot{y}=-y+x^2$.

Hence the vector field is given by $f(x,y)=(x,-y+x^2)$. In the texbook it is given that the flow generated by this vector field is $\phi_t(x,y)=(e^tx,e^{-t}y+\frac{1}{3}(e^{2t}-e^{-t})x^2)$. How they deduced this flow of that given vector field $f$?

My approach was I solved the system of differential equations that are

$\dot{x}=x$ and $\dot{y}=-y+x^2$. But I didn’t get exactly what they did. Any help/hint/solution will be really helpful for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The textbook solution is right, you can verify this by substution,and using the fact that the solution to the above system is unique.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082792/compute-the-flow-phi-t-of-mathbbxx-y-y-x?rq=1) for a description of how to solve a similar problem.

Comment: @MatthewCassell A linear problem is _not_ "similar" to a non-linear problem, no matter how typographically similar it may be. That $^2$ more or less completely invalidates the solution you link. Can it be salvaged? Maybe, but it is far from trivial.

Comment: @Arthur That isn't how I have used the word similar here though. I used the word to describe a similar problem i.e similar question, namely the fact that both questions ask how to compute the flow of a vector field and the procedure to solve both problems are the same. In both questions, one of the equations decouples one of the variables, making it possible to directly integrate, from which you can then integrate the second variable too. This seems to be how the OP did it ('I solved the system of differential equations'), so I provided an example they might be able to use.

Comment: I think if there is a precise solution then it will be really really helpful…

Comment: $\dot x=x\implies x(t)\propto e^t$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a differential equation (possibly a system)

\begin{align}
X'(t) &= F(X(t)), & X(0) &= X_{0}
\end{align}

the flow of the equation set is defined by $\varphi(X_{0}, t) = X(t)$. This implies that

\begin{align}
\varphi(X_{0}, 0) &= X_{0}, & \frac{d}{dt} \varphi(X_{0}, t) &= F(\varphi(X_{0}, t))
\end{align}

---

Solving the equation in $x$ first, then substituting this result into the equation for $y$ and solving using an integrating factor yields

\begin{align}
x &= x_{0} e^{t}, & y &= c e^{-t} + \frac{1}{3} x_{0}^{2} e^{2t}
\end{align}

where $x(0) = x_{0}$ and $c$ are the integration constants. If we set $y(0) = y_{0}$ then we have

$$y_{0} = c + \frac{1}{3} x_{0}^{2} \implies c = y_{0} - \frac{1}{3} x_{0}^{2}$$

and hence

$$\varphi(x_{0}, y_{0}, t) = (x, y) = \left( x_{0} e^{t}, y_{0} e^{-t} + \frac{1}{3} x_{0}^{2} (e^{2t} - e^{-t}) \right)$$